# How to update php 7.0 to php 7.1+ ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

I have seen some help on this online but for other distros. Before I screw something up, I would love some help on this for my exact setup which is below. This will ultimately be for upgrading Laravel to 5.6 which needs newer php version.

Ubuntu LTS, MariaDB, nginx, Laravel 5.5, AWS EC2 instance

Comment: check this https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-php-7-1-with-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-16-04-vps/

Comment: I already have a working setup on 7.0. That blog looks like it is for clean blank ubuntu installs.

Answer (score 3):

Use terminal and download repo:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
 sudo apt-get update
```

Then install:

```
 service apache2 stop
 sudo apt-get install php7.1 php7.1-common
```

Start using php 7.1:

```
 a2enmod php7.1
 service apache2 restart
```

Check version:

```
php -v
```

More for apache : https://jakelprice.com/article/how-to-upgrade-from-php-70-to-php-71

More for NGINX: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/installing-nginx-with-php7-fpm-and-mysql-on-ubuntu-16.04-lts-lemp/

Comment: That link would be very helpful if I was running apache, but I'm running NGINX so not sure this would work.

Comment: So try: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/installing-nginx-with-php7-fpm-and-mysql-on-ubuntu-16.04-lts-lemp/

Answer (score 1):

I was also wondering how to update to the latest 7.1.* version. I had PHP 7.1.7 but for Symfony 4 I need >=7.1.8.
I coudn't find an explanation how to updated. Finally I check how I installed the latest version:

```
apt-get install php7.1-curl php7.1-dev php7.1-zip php7.1-fpm php7.1-gd php7.1-xml php7.1-mysql php7.1-mcrypt php7.1-mbstring php7.1-opcach
```

As there is no minor vesion, I thought I try the same command again. And bingo, it did the update to the lasted minor verion: 7.1.22.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Vagrant + Docker
   You can use Vagrant + Docker to replicate your environment except for PHP which will be 7.1 and see if the app is still working :)
2. Use static analysis tools
   Before you start you can also use some static analysis tools to check for deprecated code:
   https://github.com/exakat/php-static-analysis-tools
3. Check offical PHP documentation
   http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.php